# PhoneGap Back Key Function

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

im having a bit troubled here. I cannot seem to understand what's the problem here. can you guys please help me? what should I do? I copied this code from here. and tried to save the project. but im having an error and it says "The method onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent) is undefined for the type object"
I am building an app with eclipse and PhoneGap 1.3.1 with jQuery 1.2.6,

Here are the code

```
package com.phonegap.mobilemone;
import com.phonegap.DroidGap;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class KeyBoard 
{

    private WebView mAppView;
    private DroidGap mGap;

    public KeyBoard(DroidGap gap, WebView view)
    {
        mAppView = view;
        mGap = gap;
    }

    public void showKeyBoard()
    {
        InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)mGap.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        // only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
        mgr.showSoftInput(mAppView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

        ((InputMethodManager)mGap.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(mAppView, 0); 

    }

    public void hideKeyBoard() 
    {
        InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) mGap.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mAppView.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            if (mAppView.canGoBack())
            {
                mAppView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have super.xxx in a method of a class without an explicit parent, so your parent is Object.  Object doesn't have an xxx method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PhoneGap, you could use the "backbutton" event and keep all of your code in JavaScript. See the example in the PhoneGap docs at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_events_events.md.html#backbutton